# Not understanding the calculation

Tags: c

I have following C program, and I'm not understanding the output of the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b, *p1, *p2, x,y,z;

    a=12;
    b=4;

    p1=&a;
    p2=&b;

    x=*p1 * *p2-6;
    y=4* - *p2 / *p1+10;

    printf("y=%d", y);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is 9. But what is the meaning of **4***?

Comment: `-` acts as a unary operator.

Comment: Gearing up for [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the meaning of 4*

The `*` there is the multiplication operator. Only one operand, `4`, is shown in that extract. The full multiplication is:

```
4* - *p2
```

which is more clearly written as

```
4 * -(*p2)
```

Write out the expression, substituting the values. We can ignore `x` since it is not used. Which leaves us:

```
y= 4* - *p2 / *p1+10;
```

And `*p2` is `b` which is `4`. And `*p1` is `a` which is 12. So the expression is:

```
y = 4 * -4 / 12 + 10;
```

And this evaluates as:

```
y = ((4 * -4) / 12) + 10;
```

Which is

```
y = (-16 / 12) + 10;
```

Which is

```
y = -1 + 10;
```

Comment: It might be helpful to explain why `-16 / 12` is `-1` and that using `4.` would result in a different answer.

Comment: `-16 / 12` equals to `1` because `-16` is integer, `12` also and then `/` is the integer division (`%` is the reminder). `16/12 = 1`, `16%12=4`. If you use `4.` then you will have `-16` but as a floating point value (the biggest type will win during the computation fo the expression), so `-16.0/12` will be about `-1.333`, added to `10` this will give about `8.666` which will then be rounded to `8` as the destination variable is an `int` (some compiler may warn about that standard conversion).

Answer (score 4):

The spacing in this line might be causing confusion:

```
y=4* - *p2 / *p1+10;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
y = 4 * (-*p2) / *p1 + 10;
```

but the spacing makes it look like a subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
4* - *p2
```

means

```
4 * (-*p2)
```

So * means simple multiplication here.

Answer (score 2):

Get familiar with the C precedence and associativity table:

[image: C Precedence and Associativity Table]

The statements will be evaluated like this (parentheses added for clarity):

```
x = ((*p1) * (*p2)) - 6;
x = ((12) * (4)) - 6  
x = (48) - 6
x = 42

y = (4 * (-(*p2)) / (*p1)) + 10;
y = (4 * (-4) / (12)) + 10
y = (-16 / 12) + 10
y = -1 + 10
y = 9
```

Comment: Precedence and associativity do not answer the question. The OP failed to recognize `*` as a multiplication operator. The precedence and associativity of multiplication would only tell the OP how the expression was organized **after** they recognized the operator. The actual problem is at a lower level of parsing.